# "Der" oder "Die" Regex?

Tags: article

Ich kenne hier zwei Argumentationsweisen, wobei ich persönlich die erste bevorzuge:

```
Regex = Regular Expression => die Expression.
```

(Expression ist laut Duden auch ein im deutschen vorhandenes Wort, feminin). Auch die englische Aussprache würde ich mit "die" benutzen.

```
Regex = Regulärer Ausdruck => der reguläre Ausdruck
```

Mir würde hier nicht gefallen, wie man Regex als Abkürzung für Regulärer Ausdruck betrachtet. (woher käme dann das "ex"?), aber ich kenne viele Leute, die so argumentieren würden.

Gibt es hier eine "richtige" Antwort? Den Begriff "Regex" selbst kennt der Duden 
nicht, soweit ich das sehe.

Comment: Die meisten Wörter mit Endung -ion sind weiblich. Deswegen greift hier **die** Expression => die Regex

Comment: Ausruck kommt von der übersetzung: `expression` --> `Ausdruck`, daher bleibt das ex erhalten

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ich denke, es gibt hier keine Regel und wie du schon gesagt hast, argumentieren die einen so und die anderen so. Ich würde z. B. deiner ersten Argumentation zustimmen, die zweite ergibt für mich wenig Sinn, weil ich das englische Wort nicht erst im Kopf übersetzen würde, um den Artikel festzustellen. Also meine Antwort:

> Die Regex

Comment: Danke für deine Antwort! wahrscheinlich würde, sollte das Wort `Regex` in den Duden aufgenommen werden, auch beides für gültig erklärt werden. Die neue Rechtschreibung ist in der Regel ja sehr liberal ;)

Comment: Wenn man „Regex“ als eigenes Wort und nicht als Abkürzung empfindet, erscheint mir auch „das Regex“ naheliegend zu sein.

Comment: @Chips_100: Mit Rechtschreiberegeln hat das nichts zu tun.

Comment: Ich kann mich nicht erinnern, je etwas anderes als _die Regex_ gehört zu haben.

Answer (score 6):

Mit der Argumentation, dass es (noch) keine Regel gibt, ist auch das Neutrum für ein Regex(-Objekt) als weitere Variante nicht "falsch". Es wird aber seltener als das Femininum oder Maskulinum verwendet:

> Das Regex

Comment: nur damit jeder Artikel mal vorkommt oder? vielleicht ein sinnvolles Argument hierfür: "das Pattern", bzw. das Muster. Regex werden ja bekanntlich mit sog. Patterns (Mustern) realisiert. Daher kann Regex auch als Verkürzung für das eigentlich geprüfte Muster stehen und damit wäre ein "das" einwandfrei begründet.

Comment: @Vogel612: genau! Nur so können wir abstimmen, was am richtigsten ist ;) Außerdem ist unsere Q/A-ratio zu niedrig.

Comment: naja. 2,5 ist nicht unbedingt schlimm, wenn man bedenkt, wie verhältnismäßig viele "ja/nein" fragen in letzter Zeit gestellt wurden

Answer (score 5):

Es gibt vermutlich keine "richtige Antwort", weil es sich um einen sehr speziellen Fachbegriff handelt, der aus dem Englischen übernommen wurde, noch dazu in einem Fachgebiet, in dem sehr häufig komplett auf Englisch kommuniziert wird.

Persönlich würde ich die erste Alternative nur akzeptieren, wenn sie wirklich komplett ins Deutsche übersetzt würde.

```
the regex = die reguläre Expression
```

Das hört sich aber sehr geschwollen an und ist schwer auszusprechen. 
Grundsätzlich ist es meines Wissens üblich, den Begriff ins Deutsche zu übersetzen und dann den entsprechenden Artikel zu wählen. Die offizielle Übersetzung für *regular expression* ist *regulärer Ausdruck*. Somit sollte es meiner Meinung nach

> der Regex

heißen.

Comment: `Grundsätzlich ist es meines Wissens nach üblich, den Begriff ins Deutsche zu übersetzen und dann den entsprechenden Artikel zu wählen` -> `das` Statement, als Übersetzung wäre es aber z.B. `die` Aussage? Mir würde keine Übersetzung dazu mit `das` als Artikel einfallen. Trotzdem +1 für die gute Begründung, dass es hier um ein durch Englisch dominiertes Fachgebiet geht, wodurch es wohl (bis jetzt) einfach noch keine "richtige" Antwort gibt.

Comment: Ich würde _die Regex_ bevorzugen, es klingt besser als die Alternativen. Wenn die Übersetzungsregel greift, dann ist's leider wohl _der Regex_, für _der reguläre Ausdruck_.